# CanLoad guard for AppModule

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

i have an angular application created using angular-cli.
I am able to use CanLoad guard for my modules. 
In my CanLoad check, I check if the user is logged in or not.

Can i use a CanLoad for AppModule also?
Basically do not load even the AppModule if the user is not authenticated.

**Reason for this question :**
All the content of the website has to be auth protected. So i am trying to reduce the payload before the user authenticates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @trichetriche answered, if you put a guard on app module the user will not be able to even login **only if app module was being bootstrapped by `main.ts`.**

You can bootstrap another module, login module for example, and from it lazy loads app module using `CanLoad`. I've never seem a pattern like this, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `CanLoad` guard **allows your users to load a part of your site**.

I think that what you want is **Lazy Loading** : the user will have the content he asked for only on request.

If you put a guard on your app module, your user won't even have the chance to login !

If so, I advise you to [take a look at the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration), which is very specific

Comment: I have lazy loading for other modules.
I am looking for something what @Pedro suggested, or any other way that achieves the same.

Comment: Well try his way, otherwise create 2 mother routes, one for login and one marked as lazy loaded (and guarded) containing all of your other routes as children, and this should answer your issue. If you need help on that, feel free to ask for a code sample, but given the issue, I'm pretty sure you have enough knowledge to make it :)

Comment: 2 mother routes..interesting.. I can reuse one for unauthroised pages if need be. Will try this out :) Thanks

Comment: This is exactly what I awlays do, two groups, one protected and the other not. This allows you to login and subscribe, and prevent the locked part of your app from loading. Keep us updated !